Why doesn't Mathematica simplify log-exp expression?
Sorry if this has been asked before, I couldn't find anything.
Why doesn't Mathematica simplify the expression $\ln(e^{-x^2/2a})$ to $-\frac{x^2}{2a}$? 
I also tried with Simplify, and also with adding some assumptions like $a > 0$, even if there is no need for it.

Log[Exp[-x^2/(2 a)]] // PowerExpand

@VaclavKotesovec Thank you! May I ask you why the Simplify commands don't work?

PowerExpand in general disregards all issues of branches of multivalued functions.

Use:PowerExpand[Log[E^(-(x^2/(2 a)))], Assumptions -> True]] that why Simplify command can't simplify.

Mathematica works with complex numbers. Another possibility: Assuming[{x > 0, a > 0}, Simplify[Log[Exp[-x^2/(2 a)]]]]

To discover why, look for counter-examples, e.g., FindInstance[Log[E^(-x^2/(2 a))] != -x^2/(2 a), {a, x}, 5]

@BobHanlon Wow, that was enlightening!!
